# problems with angularjs $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Hey i've started learning angularJS and i'm quite new to it so i gues my best bet is to ask someone.

So my $routeProvider is not routing me to anything really when i run it it wont load any partials.

The current code i'm using.

```
angular.module("list" , ['ngRoute' ])
config(function  ($routeProvider) {

    $routeprovide.
        when("/", {templateUrl:"/partials/list.html"})
    })
```

My index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html ng-app="list">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Angular Routing!</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="container">
    <a href="#lijst">
        <h2>The List!</h2>
     </a>

        <div ng-view>   </div>

    </div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I run it by using a USBWebserver app

Console Errors:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined main.js:2

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery bootstrap.js:7

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=list&p1=Error%3A%20…20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A115) angular.min.js:30
```

Comment: How do you run it and what console messages are? Also, show your index.html file.

Comment: I've added my index.html and to answer your question i run it by using USBWebserver i know it's practicly useless for anything else then php but i'm too used to it :p.

Comment: @BWI Updated an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your angular-route.js must be included after angular itself

Second, you are using some `routeprovide`, and `$routeProvider` is injected

You should do this:

```
angular.module("list" , ['ngRoute' ]).
config(function  ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.
   when("/", {templateUrl:"/partials/list.html"})
});
```

You also forgot point before config method.

And this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And, it seems, your Bootstrap.js requires jQuery to be included before it.

Comment: Oke i've figured out what the problem was fair to say you did all the heavy lifting :p
The CDN was incorrect it's supposed to be
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js

Comment: @BWI Twitter Bootstrap has dependency on jQuery as it is a jQuery plugin.